# Constantly downvoting with no reason

Tags: discussion, down-votes

There are some people (or a single person) here who have been constantly downvoting my answers since yesterday *(I don't care who they are, for the record)*.

The problem is that they don't give any reason for downvoting.

If someone downvotes an answer or a question they should give at least one reason.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Stack Exchange policy is that voting is anonymous. Giving reasons for downvotes invites arguments in the comments.

Comment: @brhans I don't think so. If there's a downvote, and if it's because there's something *technically* wrong then it should be indicated, so that the answer can be reviewed/revised or even deleted, not to provide wrong info for the OP and other people. Without arguments how could one find the correct answer?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95603/why-are-votes-anonymous-lets-make-with-the-transparency-and-have-them-publicly

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-it-required-to-provide-comments-feedback-for-downvotes-and-why-are-pr

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285081/am-i-still-supposed-to-explain-my-downvotes-or-not/285777

Comment: @brhans okay, I got the point. Everything has its own rights and wrongs, and logical explanations. I'm not questioning it. And I'm not a person who can make a judgement about this, of course. I just want this not to turn into something like downvoting based on *feelings* rather than *facts*.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I understand your frustration. I've had the same thing where someone went on a spree of downvoting my answers, even going back to years old ones to downvote. And I've also had the other situation you describe where an answer I got wrong was downvoted a few times before someone finally pointed out my error so I could fix it. So I can see that if there is something technically wrong with an answer, give the reason. But I have seen many arguments from defensive answerers too, which puts people off leaving a comment so I completely understand the other side too. It's a tricky one!

Comment: @RohatKılıç yes it's bloody annoying when people do that. Personally I favour a situation where downvotes are not allowed.

Answer (score 5):

This is a community-moderated platform.  As such, people will do all sorts of things without explanation.  It's the nature of the beast.

As for the specific instances you mention, I can't help but notice they're on questions with close votes. If a question is really very far below community standards, I've downvoted answerers just for answering.  I don't believe it's good for the community to entertain and encourage noise.  I don't see that issue with these particularly questions, but it is a possibility that somebody thought differently.

Lastly, the system has tools to detect and correct systematic voter fraud: [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Comment: `they're on questions with close votes.` funny that the close votes (and the close actions) came **after** my answers. So should I track down my answers to check if the question has close votes? And also should I check if the question *deserves* the close votes?

Answer (score 4):

A better thing to do is flag the question for moderator attention if you think there is a pattern of downvoting. Out of the last 5 questions that you posted only 2 have downvotes and one of those answers was deleted so it may not have been a good answer. One did give the reason on the deleted answer. On the other answer no reason was given and it isn't a requirement of SE to give a reason of the downvote.

Comment: do you mean "answers" and not "questions"??  Your answer would still hold.

Comment: Out of my last 5 answers, **3** of them have downvotes and yes, I deleted one (The others are [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/641619/why-cant-i-make-a-12-v-10-a-transformerless-power-supply/641643#641643) and [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/641755/can-you-charge-a-capacitor-merely-with-static-electricity-where-charges-dont-mo/641756#641756)). Because after the downvote and *its explanation* I realised that I missed a detail in the question. So I deleted my answer as it wasn't valid anymore. And that's an example of why I think a "reason" is useful.